# Is it possible to change the colour of a line of text in Eclipse Java Editor based on it's content?

Tags: java, eclipse

Specifically for editing Java code, I was wanting to know if I could change the colour of the text of any line of code beginning with the string `LOG.` which indicates a logging statement.

In this example I would like to be able to make `LOG` statement appear all in grey for example. It would help when reading code that is heavily logged.

```
public class Foo
{
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Foo.class);

    public void doSomething() {
        LOG.info("About to do something");

        // code
    }
}
```

It's probably more difficult than just identifying a single line, as logging could be split over multiple lines, and/or even contained within a `if(LOG.isDebugEnabled) {...}` block.

Visualy I would like these LOG statements/blocks to appear like the default colouring of // comments /* */

Comment: you want to colorize the content itself, and not the console output? right? I thought it was about the console output...

Comment: Yes the Java editor. Thanks, I have clarified in the Subject

Comment: There is no option for this in the preferences (at least in 4.4.1). You  can write a plugin to do this.

Comment: By the way, you might want to clarify if you want to change the color of the text in the line or the line itself.

Comment: Did you end up with a solution? After digging a bit, I'm willing to attempt to write a plugin.

Comment: No, not yet. This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11501419/how-can-i-get-syntax-highlighting-for-my-format-in-an-eclipse-text-editor) mentions some options but I was thinking like you, to have s crack at a new plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the same by writing a eclipse custom plugin.
Eclipse works to color the syntex as per rule basis.

```
ITokenScanner scanner = new RuleBasedScanner();
IToken string = createToken(colorString);    
IRule[] rules = new IRule[3];    
// Add rule for double quotes  
rules[0] = new SingleLineRule("\"", "\"", string, '\\');  
// Add a rule for single quotes   
rules[1] = new SingleLineRule("'", "'", string, '\\');   
// Add generic whitespace rule.    
rules[2] = new WhitespaceRule(whitespaceDetector);  
scanner.setRules(rules);  
scanner.setDefaultReturnToken(createToken(colorTag));
```

The createToken method instantiates a Token object for a particular color:

```
private IToken createToken(Color color) {
      return new Token(new TextAttribute(color));
   }
```

To proceed further to achieve the same you can refer to the [Eclipse FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_provide_syntax_coloring_in_an_editor%3F)

Comment: thanks, i updated your link with a more specific one from their faq

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to use the File Search tool and search on the text you want to highlight.

By searching on for example `*LOG.*` you would get a search result over an entire line.

You can access the File Search tool by selecting a piece of text in an editor and press `Ctrl + H`. You can also easily search through all files in a project or in a subdirectory.

In Eclipse it is also possible to customise the appearance of a search result to look the way you want it to. You do this in `Window > Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors > Annotations > Search Results`.

Example result, by searching on `*.getLogger()*`:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer @Lii, however my aim to have the LOG statements appear in Grey when the editor is open so that as a reader of code i am less distracted by the logging and can focus on the rest of the code logic. In a sense the LOG cals would appear in the same colour as // comments. I updated my question to clarify this.

Comment: @Brad: I see. You want them to catch your attention less, not more. The complete opposite to this.