# Have System.out.println() statements in a different color in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

In Eclipse editor I want to be able to quickly see `System.out.println` statements from  other statements. Is there a way to give them a completely different color so that I could quickly spot them when I see my code? for ex all the `System.out.println` statements are in all blue color?

P.S. I'm not asking how to color the output but the statement itself.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7091003/show-system-out-println-output-with-another-color

Comment: As far as I know, the output color is different for System.out and System.err. This might help

Comment: @Jens it's about the changing the output color of sysouts

Comment: @RobertKock sorry but i guess you haven't understood the question. I wanna give all the system.out.println statements that appear in my code a completely different color.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30208836/

Comment: AFAIK, you can't do this without writing a plugin ....

Comment: See this also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746031/how-can-i-create-a-custom-eclipse-syntax-highlighter

Comment: Can't you just search for System.out.println to have it highlighted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Have System.out.println() statements in a different color in eclipse?

No, unfortunately it is not possible.

Furthermore using `System.out.println()` and `System.err.println()` together is not allways a good idea. `System.err` has higher priority than `System.out`. So the order of output will be quit confusing.

Eclipse is a highly pluginable IDE. My suggestion is to use [Grep Console](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/grep-console), so you can use some rules (regex) to color your output.